# Problems with while loop in R

Tags: r, while-loop

I've a data frame with several variables in R. I want to use a `while` loop to go through all of the records and assign a new value to the record. I tried `while` loop which look like this:

```
h$est=""
i=0
while (i<188){
    if (h$nr==2) {h$est=="X"} 
    else {h$est==21}
    i=i+1
}
```

and it is not working at all.

I know how to make it via

```
h$est[h$nr==2]<-"X"
```

But I'd like to make it with `while` loop.

Comment: OK, I figure it out, the code is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figure it out, The code should be like that:

```
for (i in 1:length(h$Treatment)){
    if (h$Treatment[i]=="ASP") {h$est[i]=3}
    else {h$est[i]=1}
}
```